# Catch top level EF Core exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Good morning !

I am trying to find the highest exception class which throws entity framework core.
In other words is it a way to determine if exception is thrown by sql/entity framework?

Lets see below pseudo code

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Now the problem is that my piece of code may throw exception from c# itself or entity framework exception.
How do I make sure which exception do I catch ?

From the docs I can see that [SaveChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) throws bit of exceptions

Now I see those exception inherit from

> DataException

Will this solve my problem catching DataException?

```
try
{
     ...
}
catch (DataException ex)
{

}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: A good practice is to limite the size in try block... for this reason.

Comment: `SaveChangesAsync` is asynchronous, the exception will be swallowed in the task

Comment: just a pseudocode

Comment: I'm curious...why do you need to know whether the exception came from EF or not? What are you planning to do differently about exceptions from EF?

Comment: @mason lets say I have global exception handling and I would like to know if the origin is database

Comment: But why? What are you going to do differently if the origin was EF?